# Prolog puzzle baker, meatman and carpenter

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle

This is a very simple puzzle I found on the web, I don't find any solution on internet. The rules are simples:

- There are 6 artisans, M.Baker and his son, M.Carpenter and his son and M.Meatman and his son
- Each artisan can be baker, carpenter or meatman
- Son and father cannot do the same job
- The lastname couldn't be the job name (M.Baker and his son cannot be baker)

We know that:
- M.Meatman's son is baker
- M.Baker do the same job than M.Carpenter's son

I implemented this predicates:

```
% swipl prolog
% M.Meatman's son is baker
% M. Baker do job of M. Carpenter's son

% jobs
job(baker).
job(meatman).
job(carpenter).

% fathers
artisan(fatherbaker).
artisan(fathercarpenter).
artisan(fathermeatman).

% sons
artisan(sonbaker).
artisan(soncarpenter).
artisan(sonmeatman).

% some links
father(fatherbaker, sonbaker).
father(fathermeatman, sonmeatman).
father(fathercarpenter, soncarpenter).

son(S, F) :- father(F, S).

same_name(fathercarpenter, soncarpenter,  carpenter).
same_name(fathermeatman, sonmeatman, meatman).
same_name(fatherbaker, sonbaker, baker).

% rules:
do_job(Artisan, Job) :-
    Artisan==sonmeatman,!, 
    artisan(Artisan),
    job(Job),
    Job=baker. % M.Meatman's son is baker (rule 1)

do_job(Artisan, Job) :- 
    Artisan==fatherbaker,!, 
    artisan(Artisan),
    job(Job),
    do_job(soncarpenter, Job). % M.Baker do M.Carpenter's son job

% not relevant...
%do_job(Artisan, Job) :-
%        Artisan == soncarpenter,!,
%   job(Job),
%   artisan(Artisan),
%        do_job(fatherbaker, Job). % rule 2 inverted

% checking if father job is not the same and name are not forgotten
do_job(Artisan, Job) :-
    artisan(Artisan),
    job(Job),
    father(Father, Artisan),
    do_job(Father, JobFather),
    Job \== JobFather,
    not(same_name(Artisan,_,Job)).

% checking if son job is not the same and name are not forgotten
do_job(Artisan, Job) :-
    artisan(Artisan),
    job(Job),
    son(Artisan, Son),
    do_job(Son, JobSon),
    Job \== JobSon,
    not(same_name(_, Artisan, Job)).
```

Then I try:

```
swipl
?- do_job(sonmeatman, X).
X = baker ;
false.
?- do_job(fatherbaker, X).
false.
```

Can you please tell me where I'm wrong.

- Note: I'm a newbie in Prolog. I never used this language before (I'm Golang, Python, C programmer...).
- Note 2: Excuse my english, I've just translated my example that was in french, maybe jobnames or verbs are not corrects...
- Note 3: I've already tried to implement zebra puzzle and I realize that was simpler to resolve than this one... strange ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overengineering, and [reifying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_%28knowledge_representation%29) too much of the problem (a typical Prolog beginner's error). What you need to write is a six-argument predicate

```
jobs(BakerSrJob, BakerJrJob,
     CarpenterSrJob, CarpenterJrJob,
     MeatmanSrJob, MeatmanJrJob) :-
    ...
```

and in the body, constraints on those variables. E.g.

```
member(BakerJrJob, [carpenter, meatman])
```

expresses that Baker jr. is either a carpenter or a meatman, and

```
BakerJrJob \= BakerSrJob
```

expresses that father and son Baker have different jobs. A couple of these `member` calls and `\=` constraints should be enough to encode all the knowledge necessary. (Just hardcode the identity of the persons in the variable name, instead of representing and inspecting the names as atoms. Don't try to write a generic puzzle solver if you're just starting out.)

Comment: Ok, I'll check this tonight (it's 14:50 in france :)) - I'm pretty sure you're right
And to be precise, I tried some other example before... I had no problems with hierarchical resolution, path resolution etc... I just try to read docs, test and so on.

Comment: After some tests, I really fill this way is "simplier" than CappelliC solution. It's readable, simple to understand and return only one solution. CapelliC solution is nice, but returns many solution that are the same but with differents orders.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have an error here

```
...
son(Artisan, Son),
...
```

as you defined son/2 relation as son(Son,Father)

*edit* that said, I would solve in entirely different way

```
solve(Puzzle) :-
    % There are 6 artisans, M.Baker and his son, M.Carpenter and his son and M.Meatman and his son
    Puzzle = [N1/F1/S1, N2/F2/S2, N3/F3/S3],

    % Each artisan can be baker, carpenter or meatman
    Symbols = [baker, carpenter, meatman],
    permutation([N1,N2,N3], Symbols),
    permutation([F1,F2,F3], Symbols),
    permutation([S1,S2,S3], Symbols),

    % Son and father cannot do the same job
    foreach(member(_/F/S, Puzzle), F\=S),

    % The lastname couldn't be the job name
    foreach(member(N/F/S, Puzzle), (N\=F, N\=S)),

    % M.Meatman's son is baker
    member(meatman/_/baker, Puzzle),

    % M.Baker do the same job than M.Carpenter's son
    member(baker/J/_, Puzzle),
    member(carpenter/_/J, Puzzle).
```

[foreach](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foreach/2)/2 it's a tricky predicate, you could try to replace with your own (recursive) definition. [permutation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=permutation/2)/2 it's simpler, and could be easily replaced...

A last note: "Note 3: I've already tried to implement zebra puzzle and I realize that was simpler to resolve than this one... strange ? " yes it's strange, I think zebra puzzle is by far more complex than this one

Comment: "The implementation executes `forall/2` if `Goal` does not contain any variables that are not shared with `Generator`." Looks like `forall` could just be used there instead.

Comment: @WillNess: you're true, my bad

Comment: didn't know X/Y/Z notation, comparable to python tuple... really nice !

Comment: @Metal3d: you can use any binop as a pair constructor in Prolog. `a+b+c` works too, or `(A, B, C)`.